# Wordpress in HTTPS but plugins still using HTTP

Tags: wordpress, https

I'm trying to change the root URL of my Wordpress blog from http://example.com to https://example.com.

To do that I dumped my database and search and replace http to https

```
sed -i "s/http:\/\/example.com/https:\/\/example.com/g" dump.sql
```

And then reloaded my database

I also checked in the Wordpress root folder but there is no file containing http://example.com

```
grep -nr "http://example.com".
```

The problem is there are still some plugins using http for example: sitepress-multilingual-cms and AMP

Here are some of the errors I get in the console

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/dialog.css?ver=3.8.4”[Learn More] admin.php
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/otgs-ico.css?ver=3.8.4”[Learn More] admin.php
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/taxonomy-translation.css?ver=3.8.4”[Learn More] admin.php
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/js/scripts.js?ver=3.8.4”[Learn More] admin.php
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/js/otgs-notices.js?ver=4.8.3”[Learn More] admin.php
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/includes/admin-script.js?ver=0.9.67.0”[Learn More] admin.php
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/js/icl-admin-notifier.js?ver=3.8.4”[Learn More]
[...]
```

If there's no mention of http://example.com neither in the database nor in files, why are these plugins still running under http??!

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could always try [**this plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/).

Comment: Be careful when replacing strings in WP SQL dumps. As options and meta fields can contain data structures in serialized form, you might break things if your strings don't have the same lengths. That said: do you happen to be behind a reverse proxy (CloudFlare, a local nginx in front of Apache etc pp) and `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` isn't automatically set to "on"?

Comment: Simply deactivate and reactivate plugins. I have same problems and this is simplest way to fix.

Comment: @janh Yes I'm behind Cloudflare and https is not automaticaly set to on. This can be a workaround but still I don't get why it is not working

Comment: @AnhTuan I already tryed and it didn't work

Comment: Your server doesn't know the client is using HTTPS, because (I assume) the communication between CF and you is HTTP. They do send a X-Forwarded-Protocol, but I don't believe WP uses it. Have you looked at [their plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/)?

Comment: @janh Yes I have their plugin installed. You mean because I'm using the flexible option between CF and me some plugin change the protocol to HTTP?

Comment: I thought that it might be your WP not knowing the protocol between the user and CF, but their plugin should take care of that. That's strange. Are those resources enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script`/wp_enqueue_style?